# How do I dynamically assign enum values using java spring bean

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I've got the following code:

```
package vb4.email;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public enum ValidAddresses {

    // TODO: Is there a cleaner way to switch debugs?
    // How do we make this bean-able?

    @Value("${email.addresses.defaults.support}")
    DEFAULT_SUPPORT_ADDRESS("support@example.com"),
    @Value("${email.addresses.defaults.performance}")
    DEFAULT_PERFORMANCE_SUPPORT_ADDRESS("speed@example.com");

    private final String email;

    private ValidAddresses(final String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.email;
    }
}
```

As you can see from my `@Value` annotations, I'm looking to "beanify" this process. I want the benefits of the enumerable as a construct, but I'd like to make this configurable in our .properties file. Please keep in mind that the .properties file which has all the key=value pairs is used extensively throughout the site.

Please keep your answers on mark; I'm not looking to debate the validity of what is already in place. (Trust me I understand your frustration).

Comment: Enums are compile time constructs, not runtime. You cannot use `@Value` with them. The `@Target`s are `@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})`

Comment: Dang. Is there any solution to what I'm attempting to do? Can't set static variables (easily) via the bean process either...

Comment: You could have a `@Component` that has a bunch of `String` instance variables annotated with `@Value`. You won't be able to use `enum` with this alternative.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, do you have a recommended starting point? I've searched around for the past 10 minutes and can't seem to find a comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 7):

You can provide setters for your ValidAddresses enum and then use an initializer, smth like

```
@Configurable
public class EnumValueInitializer {

  @Value("${email.addresses.defaults.support}")
  private String support;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    initializeAddressesEnum();
  }

  private void initializeAddressesEnum() {
    ValidAddresses.DEFAULT_SUPPORT_ADDRESS.setEmail(support);
  }

}
```

I hope it will be helpful. Good luck.

Comment: Probably you mean `@Configuration` or `@Component`, but apart from that this is a great idea!